# Facebook's position on creating a intermediate redirect page for sharing

Tags: facebook, social-sharing-buttons

I am wondering how risky and compliant it is to create an intermediate page for social share, especially on Facebook. What I want to do is customize the OG tags for certain links and not have to update OG tags directly on the site. So I am thinking of creating a page that has my own OG tags that the FB crawler would read, but for normal users it will redirect to the real page. So actual share widget would "share" this redirect page where the crawler gets this custom content. Example of what I'd like to do: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22781663/1649495

Anyone know if this is something that can get me in trouble?

Comment: It sounds harder to maintain the meta-data about a page at a separate URL than include the correct OG tags in the page itself to me.

Comment: We do not have a choice unfortunately. The URLs that I am actually attempting to share I have no control over.